# applying a (row) function to a DataFrame changes column types

Tags: python, pandas

Having an issue with unintended changes to column types, distilled as shown below.  Column x is floats, column icol is ints.  when the testfunction (which does nothing) is applied, column icol is changed to type float64, as demonstrated by this code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1000, -1000, 1.0]})       
df['icol'] = 1
print(df.dtypes)

def testfunction(r):
    pass
    return(r)
df = df.apply(testfunction, axis='columns')
print(df.dtypes)
```

However, if I make both the x and icol columns ints, then the types do not get changed.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1000, -1000]})       
df['icol'] = 1
print(df.dtypes)

def testfunction(r):
    pass
    return(r)
df = df.apply(testfunction, axis='columns')
print(df.dtypes)
```

This is a potential hazard, for example if one may use an int column as a key later, etc.

Is this a feature, or am I doing something wrong here ?  running python 3.7.3 on ubuntu

Thanks

Comment: there are a few instances of this dtype change, I don't think it's a feature

Comment: [This is a feature](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html), but it is just yet another reason to avoid `apply(axis=1)` at all costs. It totally messes up the inherent DataFrame organization of `{col -> single_dtype}` and upcasting everything to `object` is rarely the ideal solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All Pandas operations try to be as numerically efficient as possible.  When applying an operation to a row, Pandas tries to construct a `Series` from the row first.  If the row is a mix of ints and floats, these will be converted to floats, just like when you pass a mixed list to the `Series` constructor: `Series([1000.0, 1])` is converted to all floats: i.e. `Series([1000.0, 1.0])`

Consequentially, if your row contains a string, the `object` dtype is used and all of the types are preserved at the cost of performance.  In general, you should avoid `apply` if at all possible and use other Pandas methods to get the results.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1000, -1000, 1.0]})
df['y'] = 1
df['z'] = 'hello'

print(df.apply(testfunction, axis='columns').dtypes)
# prints:
x    float64
y      int64
z     object
dtype: object
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question why the `icol` is converted to `float`. I contains only integers and has no mix in it. In your case the column `y` is not converted to float.

Comment: It is converted to float because the row is passed to the `Series` constructor.  The first row becomes `Series([1000.0, 1])` which is converted to all floats: i.e. `Series([1000.0, 1.0])`

Comment: @MykolaZotko `y` is not converted to a float because it's a string. Pandas always finds a common type that values can be upcast to.

Comment: "The row-wise operations in Pandas tries to construct " is a little bit confusing. Maybe you need to add that column-wise operations are performed row-wise under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the informative answer and comments.  Here is another simple work-around, for anyone else who doesn't want to repent from using the row function pattern:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1000, -1000.1]})       
df['icol'] = 1
print(df.dtypes)

def testfunction(r):
    pass
    return(r)

# save the types    
types = df.dtypes

df = df.apply(testfunction, axis='columns')
print(df.dtypes)

# put 'em back
df = df.astype(types.to_dict(), copy=False)

print(df.dtypes)
```